# Game speed on different devices isn't same

Tags: java, android

I have an app, in which I have constant int speed = 5; On each update, the game object (player) is moving 5px ahead. Problem is, that I can't handle that on different devices - older devices is having fx. 20fps (so 20 updates per second), and other one have 60fps. Then, my object is moving faster or slower, than it should.

I tried some screen width divisions, but didn't managed to work it.

Comment: Reading this should be useful: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/97933/framerate-is-affecting-speed-of-object/97948#97948

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be asked on  http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: surely if you're talking about 'frames per second' then your approach should be moving based on a time index base i.e get current system time, then loop checking is it say, current system time + 1/20 of a second .. if yes move 5px, get current system time and repeat loop? I'm no expert, but I would think a time based approach would give more even frame rate - as mentioned above, this would would be better suited in the gamedev forum, as this must be quite a common thing that developers overcome.

Comment: Some Android-specific tips: https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html#loops

Comment: I did this code with frame skip but it just somehow doesn't worked for me. On my tablet and phone, it just run on its own; It works like there isn't any frame skip code at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you are addressing the issue is not the best one, for instance, android can run on  many many different types of devices, all of them with different  screen sizes, that is the reason why you have to consider **how many frames per second** is your game rendered, this value is not a constant and can vary depending on devices, processes running etc... with this information  and the screen_width you can accurately calculate **how many pixels per second** an image must be moved in order to generate  the same speed effect independent  from  screen sizes...
Many game frameworks like **libgdx** can retrieve this information  (the name it "delta" as a time diff. between 2 consecutive frames).
Lets break it down with an example: 
Consider the tablet in the image below, your game needs to translate the blue dot, form the left to the right in exactly one second.
So the solution to this is completly dependent from the table size and the tablet capabilities.

If you have a Tablet with hypothetically 100 as a width and rendering a 10 Frames per Second, this means your `onDraw` Method will be called 10 times per second, so the blue dot can be increase its position in a rate of 10 pixels per rendered frame in order to be translated from the left to the rigth in **1 second**, if the delta changes, no matter why, then the speed will be the same.

[image]

Now I hope with this information you can get what you need to develop your game.

Comment: Sorry for dumb, but I didn't get it. You mean something like dividing 5px (speed) with current FPS?

Comment: I got it now. Thank you so much jipr311! (you have vote up, my votes will be public soon)

Comment: What to do if I need to get a constant speed (with these calculation you wrote there), before the game begans? I mean, I need to create it in surfaceCreated.