# Using delta time vs not using it

Tags: java, libgdx

I've started learning `libGDX` and went not very deep for now. In one of the tutorials I have noticed that people use `deltatime` which is (if I understood it correctly) time between 2 frames which should be around 0.016 (60 fps). Then I saw a person stating that it's a bad practice to use `deltatime` as it is quite difficult to implement the right way.

Here are two questions I have about the `deltatime`

1. When do you want to use it and when do you want to use a fixed number?
2. I also suppose that `deltatime` is a wrong thing to use in multiplayer network games because people may get different fps and the calculation will not work as intended. Is it a valid statement or am I wrong?

Comment: take a look at this comment http://stackoverflow.com/a/33837173/982161

Comment: Fixed timestep is always better than using deltatime: Read this: http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/

Comment: @TomGrillGames I don't think suggesting fixed timesteps are always better is particularly helpful for someone just starting out. You need a fairly comprehensive understanding of what a deltaTime is and when you might want to use one (as answered by CConard96 below) before that article is really relevant. Not saying it's not good, just maybe not suitable for what OP is asking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the event of differing FPS or uncapped FPS (no vsync), you may still want different aspects of the game to run at the same speed. For example, you probably don't want a player moving around at twice the speed in they are getting 120 FPS while a player getting 60 FPS walks around at normal speed.

```
moveSpeed= baseSpeed * delta;
```

The higher a person's frame frame, the lower the delay between frames so your can multiply a base speed by the delta to get a scaled movement speed.